# CoreData with transformable attribute fails on save

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to use CoreData and save a custom class attribute in one of the entities. The way to do that seems to be to use Transformable:

[image]

And then I try to add a single element and save it as:

```
import UIKit;
import CoreData;

public class EntityData: NSObject, NSSecureCoding
{
    public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { true }

    public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(self.name, forKey: "name");
    }

    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String;
    }

    var name: String?;

    init(name: String?) {
        self.name = name;
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(_: animated);

        let context  = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext;
        
        let entity = Entity(context: context);
        
        entity.id = URL(string: "google.com");
        entity.data = EntityData(name: "Foo");
        
        do {
            try context.save();
        } catch {
            print("While saveing: \(error)");
        }
    }
}
```

This fails with:

```
2021-09-30 13:12:58.865312+0400 tmpCoreData[5815:170015] [error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x6000034f6040> , <shared NSSecureUnarchiveFromData transformer> threw while encoding a value. with userInfo of (null)
CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x6000034f6040> , <shared NSSecureUnarchiveFromData transformer> threw while encoding a value. with userInfo of (null)
2021-09-30 13:12:58.865530+0400 tmpCoreData[5815:170015] [error] error: -executeRequest: encountered exception = <shared NSSecureUnarchiveFromData transformer> threw while encoding a value. with userInfo = (null)
CoreData: error: -executeRequest: encountered exception = <shared NSSecureUnarchiveFromData transformer> threw while encoding a value. with userInfo = (null)
2021-09-30 13:12:58.865983+0400 tmpCoreData[5815:170015] [error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x6000034e4300> , <shared NSSecureUnarchiveFromData transformer> threw while encoding a value. with userInfo of (null)
CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x6000034e4300> , <shared NSSecureUnarchiveFromData transformer> threw while encoding a value. with userInfo of (null)
2021-09-30 13:12:58.866158+0400 tmpCoreData[5815:170015] [error] error: -executeRequest: encountered exception = <shared NSSecureUnarchiveFromData transformer> threw while encoding a value. with userInfo = (null)
CoreData: error: -executeRequest: encountered exception = <shared NSSecureUnarchiveFromData transformer> threw while encoding a value. with userInfo = (null)
2021-09-30 13:12:58.866558+0400 tmpCoreData[5815:170015] [error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x6000034ec0c0> , <shared NSSecureUnarchiveFromData transformer> threw while encoding a value. with userInfo of (null)
CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x6000034ec0c0> , <shared NSSecureUnarchiveFromData transformer> threw while encoding a value. with userInfo of (null)
2021-09-30 13:12:58.900366+0400 tmpCoreData[5815:170015] [error] error: -executeRequest: encountered exception = <shared NSSecureUnarchiveFromData transformer> threw while encoding a value. with userInfo = (null)
CoreData: error: -executeRequest: encountered exception = <shared NSSecureUnarchiveFromData transformer> threw while encoding a value. with userInfo = (null)
2021-09-30 13:12:58.912131+0400 tmpCoreData[5815:170015] [error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x6000034f83c0> , <shared NSSecureUnarchiveFromData transformer> threw while encoding a value. with userInfo of (null)
CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext: 0x6000034f83c0> , <shared NSSecureUnarchiveFromData transformer> threw while encoding a value. with userInfo of (null)
While saveing: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "A Core Data error occurred."
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. This is all the code I have, there is nothing else going on that I've added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A transformable attribute requires a class conforming to `NS(Secure)Coding` (not `Codable`!) and the implementation of archiving the object(s). Note the `NSSecureUnarchiveFromData` errors.

In the Swift world consider to declare the attribute as `String`, encode the object to JSON with `Codable` and add a computed property for the seamless conversion.

Comment: I've tried implementing NSCoding and NSSecureCoding. Both of them give me the same error.

Comment: Add your implementation of `NSCoding` and the code to (un)archive the object. Again, the JSON solution is more efficient.

Comment: I added the implementation to my question. Could you elaborate on why the JSON solution is more efficient? I would effectively have to keep track of when an object is mutated to edit its json, etc.

Comment: `EntityData(name: "Foo")` is not sufficient. You have to archive the object with `NSKeyedArchiver`. `NSCoding` is Objective-C related, the JSON solution is more lightweight because it can handle even structs. And as mentioned the conversion is easier to implement. By the way this is Swift: No trailing semicolons.

Comment: PS: I don't understand the sense of saving **one** `String` in a transformable attribute anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The one `String` class is just a simple example for this website.

Comment: I used JSON instead. Transformable seems to be very clumsy.